# I installed XAMMP on my machine, where do I have to put my HTML files to view them?

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

If I enter 'localhost' on my browser, I'm taken to XAMPP's welcome screen so everything is installed correctly.

What folder do I have to put my html files in?
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be under XAMPP->htdocs.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is go up one folder and if you see something along the lines of `public_html`, `htdocs`, or `www`, it should go there.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, these preinstallers reconfigure apache to a htdocs(or webdir, public_html, www) folder, directly in the xampp folder. Look under `C:\XAMPP\xampp` in your case